# With firebase, is it possible to auto-generate a username/password? If so, can you set the username/password expire after a few days

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for authentication on my app. There only needs to be one username/password for it, and after X time, i need for it to expire and to generate a new one. I was wondering if that was possible at all

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in features for automatic account generation or expiration in Firebase Authentication. However, since it has an API, you can implement all of these yourself. For example, here is [documentation on creating a new user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user), and [updating a user profile, such as changing their password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

You'll typically need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) for these operations, since they require administrative access to your project. That also means you should run them in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks ill try it out!